# Accidental Impedance Mismatch on Trace

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, rf

I have a 50 ohm SMA connector input, the track connecting the input to the circuit is mismatched by about half, .60mm instead of .33mm. Altium reads the impedance at that track at about 25 ohms, half of the 50 ohms matched. The boards has already been ordered and I cannot wait to order a new board with the track width fixed. What kind of problems can I expect to arise and is there any fix applicable? Could I remove/scratch the track from the SMA connector and then jump it?

[image]

Comment: What is the track "length"  ... And what frequency and/or timing speed working ?

Comment: Track length from input to matched track/C9 net is 15.425mm, frequency is 2.24GHz

Comment: May be AppCAD from Avago Technnologies may help you. I search the web address ...

Comment: https://www.broadcom.com/appcad

Comment: The lambda @2.24 GHz is 13.4 cm divided by sqrt (diélectric permittivity of pcb board). So 15.5 mm is (?) a "little distance" ... and you can be considering that it is not a 'transmission line' ...

Comment: Choose option "transmission line" in AppCAD, then "Wire over Ground plane" then choose "height" of wire for 50 Ohm. We can then lift the added wire (remove the invalid track).